# Meaning of double arrow $\Leftrightarrow$ symbol in signal processing context

Tags: notation, signal-processing

What is the meaning of the double left-right arrow in the following context? This is from a signal processing paper, *Alias-Free Digital Synthesis of Classic Analog Waveforms*.

> For a general discrete-time signal $x(nT_s)$ which has been
> uniformly sampled at twice its highest frequency, exact
> bandlimited interpolation, which we call sinc interpolation,
> is carried out as
> $$x(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty x(nT_s)h_s(t\Leftrightarrow nT_s)$$
> $$=\frac{sin(\pi F_st)}{\pi F_s} \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty x(nT_s)\frac{(\Leftrightarrow 1)^n}{t\Leftrightarrow nT_s}$$
> where $$h_s(t) \triangleq sinc(F_st) \triangleq \frac{sin(\pi F_st)}{\pi F_st}.$$

I have read in [Wikipedia's list of mathematical symjbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols), and in [other questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2178318/single-and-double-implication-arrow) that it means *if and only if*. However, this does not make sense to me here.

There is also [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/636823/621968) suggesting "the $p\Leftrightarrow q$ symbol is just a strange font substitution for $p−q$", which I would indeed find very strange. Most of the answer is specific to a different context which I don't understand well enough to verify it.

I'm especially confused about its use in the second line: $(\Leftrightarrow 1)^n$ where there isn't even a left-hand term.

This must be a specialised usage. What is it?

#### Edit

If it *is* being used as **iff**, could someone walk me through how to interpret that? eg. Could I unpack the first line of the equation as

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty x(nT_s) \begin{cases} h_s(t), & t = nT_s \\ [...], & otherwise \end{cases} $$

and what would go in place of $[...]$? How to then unpack the expression $(\Leftrightarrow 1)^n$?

Comment: If that is the case, how do I evaluate it when the condition is not satisfied? I've added a follow-up question

Comment: It's a typo for a  '$-$' sign.  The expression is a convolution.

Comment: @AndyWalls As in minus??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a '$-$' sign.

$\sin(\pi F_s [t - nT_s]) =\sin(\pi F_s t)\cos(\pi F_s nT_s) - \cos(\pi F_s t)\sin(\pi F_s nT_s) = \sin(\pi F_s t)(-1)^n -\cos(\pi F_s t)(0)$

since $F_sT_s =1$ by definition.

The overall expression is a convolution.

Comment: Thank you, that's a very helpful expansion. But why on earth would someone print that for a minus sign? That's just pure obfuscation.

Comment: Blame computers and software and editors.  That's not something a signal processing expert did.

Comment: Fair enough I suppose. Now I’m really curious to know how that confusion could arise. Surely if you’re marking up in LaTeX there’s no proximity between the two.